# In sitecore 8,I get error as "The Controls Collection can't be modified because the control contains Code blocks i.e( <%...%>)"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

[image]In sitecore 8, After publishing my VS solution I am able to see few pages while for few pages I get error as "THe Controls Collection can't be modified because the control contains Code blocks i.e( <%...%>)". Please help.

Comment: Google has lots of answers on that error (including here on SO), but if you need specific help we should see some code...

Comment: @Gatogordo, I have added snapshot of error.It would be great if I can get any suggestion for this issue.

Comment: Most likely your syntax is not correct somewhere. Check your <% %> tags once more.

Comment: I get this error for the home page of my site,while few other pages are running fine.

Comment: Did you do what others and I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I tried by replacing all the <%= with <%#, in binding the controls, in home.aspx and all ascx still issue not resolved.

Comment: Without seeing some code we're shooting in the dark. Update your question with code examples.

Comment: code examples of Home page?

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.tcsc.com/sitecore-layouts-and-code-blocks/

Answer (score 1):

This is typically caused by using code blocks in a Sitecore layout. This will work fine in the Content Editor however as soon as you go to use the Page Editor or Preview a page you will run into this error. This happens because Sitecore dynamically adds the ribbon control to the page which modifies the controls collection.

However because you've mentioned you are seeing it on a published page this may actually not be related to Sitecore and it's ribbon control at all (this can happen in vanilla Asp.net as well). It could just be happening because you are using code blocks to inject values into the header of the page and the controls you are referencing have not been rendered yet.  Based on the error message included it looks like you (or at least the Active Commerce skin) may be trying build the meta tags in this fashion.

There are a few options here for solving this issue:

- If trying to inject something into your JavaScript (e.g. the ClientID of a field) then do so using Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock.
- If you are trying to inject a value into JavaScript you can also move the JavaScript block to the end of the page (before the  tag) or in a script block after the control it is referencing. Having it in the  will often result in this error.
- Use a data binding block instead (<%# %>). If you are accessing a page property you will need to add Page.DataBind() in the Page_Load.

If those don't get you up and running share any relevant code and I should be able to help you further.

References:

http://www.tcsc.com/sitecore-layouts-and-code-blocks/ https://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/how-to-fix-this-the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-i-e-lt-gt